# Probability that at least 2 people chose the same number

Tags: probability

Each person in a group of n people is requested to select a whole number between 1 to k. Describe the probability that at least 2 people chose the same number.

My answer was
$P(x)=favorable\ cases / posible\ cases$
$P(x) = C_2^nC_{n-2}^K\ /\ Vr_{K}^n$

But the teacher told me it was wrong. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Hint: It says 'at least two' not 'exactly two'.

Comment: I see that in the second combinatorial. I leave 2 fixed in the first and in the second the rest of the cases, whether they are the same or not, am I wrong?

Comment: What does $x$ represent? What does your denominator mean? What does $\binom{k}{n-2}$ have to do with the problem? As it stands, it makes very little sense at all. (And you should consider separately what happens when $n>k$.)

Comment: What is $V$?  What is $r$?

Comment: When $n> k$ the probability is 1, my denominator means the number of different numbers that $n$ people can choose, it is a variation with repetition and $C_{n-2}^K$ means the rest of the numbers chosen by the rest of the people (having 2 already fixed)

Comment: In your numerator, you are missing the point that $n$ people all could have the same birthday... $(n-1)$ could have the same birthday, If you make groups of people sharing the same number, you could have $x$ number of groups where people in each group share the same number. All of these cases and many more are all part of _at least_ two people share the same number.

Comment: If $n>k$, then the answer must be $1$ by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: How would you find the probability that in a group of $n$ people ($ n \leq 365$), at least two people share the same birthday? This problem is similar.

Comment: Looking at the answer @Stacker gave me could be $P = 1 - \frac{V_{n}^{365}}{365^n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k\ge n$, it's just 1- the probability that everyone chooses different numbers.

$1-\displaystyle \frac{k*(k-1)*...*(k-n+1)}{k^n}$